# Python tkinter change background color with a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, tkinter, background-color

This is part of my code where I'm trying to create a user input field where a user can write the type of color they want their background to be, then click the button below it and make it happen.

I've used exactly the same code to change the color of my brush "
`create_oval(color, outline)` and it worked yet, it doesn´t seem to affect the bg color, any suggestions?

```
import tkinter
background = "white"
okno = tkinter.Tk()
okno.title("Project")
platno = tkinter.Canvas(okno, height = 300, width = 300, bg = background)
platno.pack()

 def background_color():
    background = vstup2.get()
    vstup2.set(background)

tkinter.Label(okno,text = "Background color :", bg = "white", width = 30).pack()
vstup2 = tkinter.StringVar()
tkinter.Entry(okno,textvariable = vstup2, ).pack()
tkinter.Button(okno,width=30, text="Set the color of a background", command=background_color).pack()
```

Comment: Which widget do you want to change the color?

Comment: Are you using `StringVar` to change colors?

Comment: You don't seem to be attempting to change the background anywhere.

Comment: This: `vstup2.set(background)` should read: `platno.configure(bg=background)`. Also fix your indentation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed your code by using the `.config()` function. In the background changing function, you don't attempt to change the background. You only change a `StringVar()`, which doesn't change the background anyways.

I also made your gui look better, like so:

```py
import tkinter
background = "white"
okno = tkinter.Tk()
okno.title("Project")
okno.config(bg = "white")
platno = tkinter.Canvas(okno, height = 300, width = 300, bg = background, highlightthickness = 0)
platno.pack()
def background_color():
    background = vstup2.get()
    try:
        platno.config(bg = background)
    except:
        pass

tkinter.Label(okno,text = "Background color :", bg = "white", width = 30).pack()
vstup2 = tkinter.StringVar()
tkinter.Entry(okno,textvariable = vstup2, bg = "white").pack()
tkinter.Button(okno,width=30, text="Set the color of a background", command=background_color, relief = "flat", activebackground = "white", bd = 0, bg = "white").pack()

okno.mainloop()
```

Output:
[image]

You also have to add a `.mainloop()` at the end. In some text editors, if you don't add that, the program wont run properly.

Hope this helps!